# Выполнение Java-апплетов на Android

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток! Нужна Ява для Андроид планшета, чтобы можно было работать с Интернет-Банком, подписывать платежные документы. Такое на сегодня возможно? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

J2ME Эмулятор что ли? Если да, [официальный сайт](http://www.netmite.com/android/) J2ME Runner. [Справка по конвертации](http://www.renjusblog.com/2010/09/install-jar-files-android-j2me-runner.html) .jar в .apk.